# Javascript - Lodash / Underscore compare two objects and change values based on their keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

There is a small problem

I need to compare two objects, and based on the same keys in these objects pass values from second object to the original object.

Original object

```
{
   content: "Old Value",
   height: 200,
   id: "15a2d286-d123-1cf0-4e40-b043b055a49f",
   type: "location",
   units: "some unit value",
   width: 200,
}
```

Second object

```
{
   units: "some unit value", 
   content: "New Value"
}
```

Keys is not necessary to check for compliance

The output will be something like that

```
{
   content: "New Value", // changed value
   height: 200,
   id: "15a2d286-d123-1cf0-4e40-b043b055a49f",
   type: "location",
   units: "some unit value", // changed value
   width: 200,
}
```

Is there any elegant solution to this problem with Lodash or Underscore?

Comment: What is your comparison based on? The `units` value?

Comment: Seems like you just want to merge two objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the trick (using lodash)

```
var source = {
  content: "Old Value",
  height: 200,
  id: "15a2d286-d123-1cf0-4e40-b043b055a49f",
  type: "location",
  units: "some unit value",
  width: 200,
},
source2 = {
  units: "some unit value", 
  content: "New Value"
}
_.assignIn(source , source2 );
```

Comment: if i may ask, what is the difference between _.assignIn and _.merge ? for , _.merge(source,source2)  seems to do the same thing !